# Density and $\lambda$ - measurability of a Radon measure

Tags: measure-theory, euclidean-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

> **Question**: Let $\lambda$ be a Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that
>
> $$ \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{\lambda(A \cap B(x,r))}{\lambda(B(x,r))}=0 \ \ \ \text{for $\lambda$ almost all $x \in$ $\mathbb{R^n}\setminus A$}$$
>
> if and only if $A$ is $\lambda$-measurable.

I have the following corollary which may be useful,

> A measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Radon measure if and only if it is locally finite and Borel regular.

Im assume that the case "if $A$ is $\lambda$ - measurable...." is easily shown using

$$\mu(C)=\mu(C \cap A)+\mu(C \setminus A) $$

Now if we suppose that $\displaystyle \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{\lambda(A \cap B(x,r))}{\lambda(B(x,r))}=0 \ \ \ \text{for $\lambda$ almost all $x \in$ $\mathbb{R^n}\setminus A$}$. I cannot see how to proceed. Could someone please guide me as to how to do this.

Comment: My first idea would be to try to express $A = B \cup N$ for a Borel set $B$ and a $\lambda$ null set $N$. It could possibly better to seek an expression of $A^c$ instead of $A$ in that form.

Comment: Could we argue that if $A$ is not measurable then $\lambda(E) < \lambda(E \cap A) + \lambda(E \setminus A)$ for all $E \subset X$. This equivalent to $\lambda(A) < \lambda(E \cap A)$ for all $E \subset  X$. Then we could take E to be $B(x,r)$. Would this work?

Comment: Sadly, you can **not** do that, because if $A$ is not measurable, this only implies that there is **some** $E$ such that $\lambda(E) < \lambda (E\cap A) + \lambda(E \setminus A)$. Thus, you do not know a priori that you can take $E= B_r (x)$.